# Maven jar plugin looking for non-existent log4j file

Tags: java, maven, logging, jar, log4j

My project has no log4j config file referring to C:\log4j-application.log but maven has an error because it doesn't exist.  This is on a  linux system. 
Error from "mvn package" command:

```
 Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] a ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.943 s]
[INFO] b ............................................. SUCCESS [  8.659 s]
[INFO] c ............................................. SUCCESS [  4.295 s]
[INFO] d ............................................. SUCCESS [  2.867 s]
[INFO] e ............................................. FAILURE [  0.093 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.071 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-16T17:53:42-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/1029M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) on project web: Error assembling JAR: C:\log4j-application.log not found. -> [Help 1]
```

parent pom.xml (module e's pom has no build/execution/package info, only dependencies):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>../b</module>
        <module>../e</module>
        <module>../d</module>
        <module>../e</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>all-in-one</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Typical log4j.properties in my app:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

org.jooq.Constants.level=WARNING
~
```

What could cause this?  Attempted so far:

- mvn clean, deleted .m2/repository
- removing log4j from module e
- Lots of googling

Comment: If module `e` is failing, why would you show the parent pom and not the pom for module `e`?

Comment: Tha path "C:\log4j-application.log" seems to be strange for linux system ?

Comment: @kdgregory module e's pom only has dependency info, not any maven-jar configuration or other build details that I thought could be causing the problem.  The parent has that so I thought it might be helpful.  If you think the dependency list alone could be causing a problem I can add it.

Comment: @RajindRuparathna Agreed.  Possibly there's a log4j default I need to override with a linux path? Haven't seen anything like that from Google searches though.

Comment: Can you add module e pom file ?

Comment: Do you have an application.properties file somewere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this was definitely an oversight on my part.  There was a lingering file called C:\log4j-application.log in e/src/main/resources that was causing the issue. Once it was deleted and I ran a maven clean everything worked as expected.

I think a log4j config I had started with had the file set to C:\log4j-application.log and then I started getting errors because it didn't exist.  Well at the time I created a file with that name using `touch` in a few locations to bypass the error but I never deleted all of them. It was an empty file so my `grep -R log4j-application .` commands never found it (I was expecting that some config file referenced the file).  Facepalm.